# Bayesian inference with sampling and mixture models

Tags: bayesian, sampling, conditional-probability

I'm having some trouble doing Bayesian inference on an experience I have in hands. I apologize in advance if it is too complex, but I couldn't find a trivial way to split it in several parts.

---

Let there be $N$ bags, each of them containing some balls. They do not have the same number of balls, but the number of balls they have follows a known distribution. Moreover, we know the total number of balls, $M$.

We know that a random subset of the $M$ balls are marked differently from the others. It is not necessarily a proper subset - the size of the subset can be anything from 0 to $M$, inclusive. Consider that there is no correlation between the "marked status" of a ball and the bag it is in.

Finally, we are allowed to look at a random sample of the $N$ bags (consider a simple random sample with a known probability $p$). The objective is to guess the total number of marked balls inside all bags.

This experiment will be done a large number of times and the accuracy of the guesses will be measured by taking the [mean absolute error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) of each experiment and calculating the average of those errors in the end.

---

We do not control most of the parameters above, and therefore I'd prefer not to rely on strategies such as the CLT, that assume certain conditions for the parameters.

My high-level strategy so far was:

1. Model, using numerical means, the distribution of the number of marked balls the sample of bags would have, given the total number of marked balls;
2. Start with a prior of believing that all possible numbers of marked balls are equally probable and update my belief using Bayesian inference after I know how many marked balls my sample has;
3. Give the median of the posterior distribution as the guess that minimizes the mean absolute error.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with that approach? Is there any simpler solution? If the approach is correct, can you guide me in the process of modelling the distribution in step 1?

Comment: I have trouble understanding why the bags play any role as such in your problem. In which sense does the problem differ from an hypergeometric model?

Comment: The role of the bags is to highlight that the marking process and the sampling process are not done on the same unit - balls are individually marked, while you sample bags, not balls. I think that the fact that the distribution of balls per bag follows a known but arbitrary distribution adds extra complexity, as depending on the distribution you may not be able to see some outcomes in the sample or you may get extra information from the sample outcome. Nonetheless, I think the number of marked balls in a bag can indeed be modelled with a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: This is my point: the marking process is independent from the sampling process and the distribution on the number of balls per bag has no impact on the posterior on the total number of marked balls. Sampling a certain number of bags and all the balls within those bags is equivalent to sampling all those balls at once in terms of infering about the number of marked balls.

Comment: Hmm, let me try to give a counterexample. Let N=M=10. Let us consider two different balls per bag distributions. In the first, each bag has exactly 1 ball. After looking at a sample of 5 bags and see K marked balls, our best guess will be 2*K - the right answer can be anywhere between K and 5+K. In the second case, a bag has either 0 or 10 balls. As M=10, the only possible configuration is having a single bag with all the balls. The posterior is very different: if we see at least one ball in our sample, we know for sure the answer. If we see no balls, we learned nothing from the sample.

Comment: The fact that it gives a different answer is not a counterexample, simply the fact that you have two different observations with two different conclusions. **Request:** Could you write down the entire distribution of your experiment?

Comment: @xian Do you mean the distribution of balls per bag? In the instance of the experiment I am working now, it is best modelled by an exponential distribution with lambda 0.1, but where no empty bags are seen (they are filtered beforehand). For simplicity, you can discard this last detail and assume empty bags can appear.

Comment: The exponential distribution is a continuous distribution, how does it apply to the number of balls per bag?

Comment: In my original experiment (the problem I am working on is not about bags and balls, of course - I explained it that way so as to simplify the business domain in the hope it would be easier to understand), I have access to a large dataset of bags and their respective number of balls and either find an approximate distribution or use the frequency table as a "numerical" distribution. The shape of the distribution resembles closely an exponential one in the sense that a large number of bags have few balls and a minority has a lot of balls.

Comment: If it helps you explain your point, you can pick any right-skewed distribution (i.e. do not assume it is symmetric) and use it as example, I think it would help me nonetheless :)